# Show multiple calendars in overlay view by default

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

In MS Outlook 2007/2010, it's possible to show multiple calendars overlayed on each other (a la Google Calendar; see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/view-calendars-side-by-side-or-overlaid-HA001230157.aspx#BM4). However, it appears that in order to do this, you must first open the calendars side-by-side and then press the little left-arrow button to "combine" them into an overlaid view. Is there a way to make "overlaid" the default view for multiple calendars (again, a la Google Calendar)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the default settings that control when the display changes back and forth. You'll find that in Options. Once done, open all the calendars, click the arrow that makes them glue together and they should stay that way.

The main problem is that Outlook doesn't remember your preference to show all the calendars so when you reopen Outlook you have to reselect the ones that aren't showing. To make that easier, put them all in one group along with your default calendar, then you can just click on the group rather than each calendar.

Comment: I don't see an option to change when the display changes; the closest thing I see is an option to change what number of calendars will trigger a transition to or from schedule view.

Comment: That's the one. Sorry, I don't have an Outlook 2010 system to hand.

Comment: Where are "Options", please? And how does one make a "group"?

Comment: Options are under the File tab.

Comment: Hmmm--in Outlook 2007, I set "automatically switch from vertical view to schedule view" to occur when I've got 2 or more calendars open, but that didn't seem to have any effect...not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Ah, got it, "vertical" is apparently the view that I *do* want.

Answer (score 5):

There is an option in each calendar to displayed it as an Overlay. Right click on each calendar and select Overlay:

[image]

Overlay can also be set from the view menu

[image]

Comment: Does this set overlay as the default, though?

Comment: Yes Outlook remembers when you set a particular calendar to display as Overlay and displays it overlayed from then on.

Comment: But it doesn't set it as the default for *all* calendars, does it? The other answer appears to be closer to what I'm looking for. Thanks, though.

Comment: No, since you are setting the Overlay for a particular calendar rather than all of them.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working in outlook365. The overlay doesnt persist after closing the program

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the "back" button/action for me that resets the Outlook calendar view to a single calendar in Office 365. If I add multiple calendars in Overlay mode, and then use the side buttons to navigate between Mail and Calendar etc. the overlay persists. If at any time I use the "back" button I've added to the "Quick Access" toolbar at the top, my overlays and other calendar views are not displayed by default and I have to add them again.